# How to monitor change in files in windows system in c# using filesystemwatcher

Tags: c#, wpf, filesystemwatcher

Currently i am using filesystemwatcher class to watch the file changes But in my case i have millions of file on different- different location in the system, so i have to create millions instance of fileststemwatcher class which is causing the performance issue.

Please tell how can i maximize the performance or is there another way to monitor the all files in c#.

Comment: Obvious question- are you using the IncludeSubdirectories property?

Comment: Why do you have to create millions instances of fsw classes ? Do you use the "IncludeSubdirectories" feature and filename filtering ?

Answer (score 3):

FileSystemWatcher is the normal way. I suggest you watch for files at a higher level - eg. all changes at the drive level, and only respond to those that are in folders you are interested in.

Once you get a "Changed" event for example, you can check the FullPath property on the FileSystemEventArgs that is passed to your event handler.

And I assume you are already watching at a folder-level, not individual files.

Comment: If i will watch all changes at the drive level, then their is a chance of getting more unusual changed event. because for example if a am monitoring drive C: then their are many process which is continuously changing the some files like(log file), in that case it will not cause any performance issue.